# Can I run two windows with input at once Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I'm trying to create a window that can do multiple things e.g open a calculator, etc. I'm using Pygame to create the original window. The calculator is made with Tkinter and is fully functional.
After a certain event:

```
      t1 = Thread(target=i['function']())
      t1.start()
```

this happens creating the calculator and the calculator works perfectly. However, the Pygame window won't take any input and won't allow me to open another calculator or even close the window. I would like to know if/how it's possible to make this work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please provide code!

Comment: @youssefjallouli What code should I provide, I would be happy to provide anything.

Comment: You're not actually using a thread here. `target=i['function']()` _immediately_ calls `i['function']()` and then sets the return value as the target.

Comment: @BryanOakley Then how should I do it?

Comment: Remove the `()`, assuming `i['function']` is actually a function.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Bryan Oakley for helping me with this but I wasn't actually creating threads I was just calling the function I had to write it like this:

```
t1 = Thread(target=i['function'])
t1.start()
```